# Can these two matrices (composed of fifth roots of unity) satisfy the following determinant relations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

I have two 4x3 complex matrices whose elements are composed by fifth roots of 1. There is no zero entry. Let $\gamma=e^{2i \pi /5}$, then

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma^{a_1} & \gamma^{a_2} & \gamma^{a_3} \\
  \gamma^{b_1} & ... & ... \\
  \gamma^{c_1} & ... & ... \\
  \gamma^{d_1} & ... & ...
\end{pmatrix}$ and  $B=\begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma^{e_1} & \gamma^{e_2} & \gamma^{e_3} \\
  \gamma^{f_1} & ... & ... \\
  \gamma^{g_1} & ... & ... \\
  \gamma^{h_1} & ... & ...
\end{pmatrix}$.

If any row is removed from either $A$ or $B$, the determinant of the resulting 3x3 is always non-zero. Furthermore, I have a somewhat odd condition: let $|A_x|$ ($|B_x|$) be the determinant of the 3x3 submatrix of $A$ ($B$) obtained by removing the $x$-th row, then

$\frac{|A_1|}{|B_1|}=\frac{|A_2|}{|B_2|}=\frac{|A_3|}{|B_3|}$.

My question is: when can this actually happen? What are the conditions on the integers (mod $5$) $a_1,...,h_3$ such that these properties are satisfied?

Comment: Can we use unity itself as a root?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. It does appear in the matrices.